# React radio button not getting checked but working functionally fine

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, jsx, checked

I have following react component which has two radio buttons.

```
export default class DemoApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onThemeChange = ::this.onThemeChange;
    this.state = {
      theme: "dark"
    };
  }

  onThemeChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      theme: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label htmlFor="light-theme">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="light"
                      onChange={this.onThemeChange}
                      checked={this.state.theme === "light"}
                      name="theme"
                      id="light-theme"
                    />
                    light
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="radio">
                  <label htmlFor="dark-theme">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value="dark"
                      name="theme"
                      checked={this.state.theme === "dark"}
                      onChange={this.onThemeChange}
                      id="dark-theme"
                    />
                    Dark
                  </label>
                </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The radio buttons are working fine functionally. But they are got getting checked i.e. only default one gets checked and it remains checked even if the state value is changes. I have tried with defaultChecked prop too as follows but no luck.

```
<div className="radio">
  <label htmlFor="dark-theme">
    <input
      type="radio"
      value="dark"
      name="theme"
      checked={this.state.theme === "dark"}
      onChange={this.onThemeChange}
      id="dark-theme"
    />
    Dark
  </label>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to find out what wrong am I doing?

Comment: You need to bind like this.onThemeChange = this.onThemeChange.bind(this); but you are doing something incorrect

Comment: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rswejs) other than your binding of `onThemeChange()`, what you are doing seems right.

Comment: @Think-Twice that's abosultely fine its just a syntctic sugar via babel using "transform-function-bind" plugin.